# PHP doesn't redirect to specified page

Tags: php

I tried `sleep()` function and redirecting by meta tags. I have the following code. What do i do wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Please wait... Generating reports...</title>
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="images/log.png">
</head>

<body>
<center>
<div style="margin-top:200px;">
<embed src="images/loadingcircle2.swf" width="30" height="30"></embed><br />
<i style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#004e49; font-size:12px;">Generating the results. Please wait...</i>
<?php
header( "refresh:5; url=results.php" ); 
?>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `header` functions should be placed before sending data to the browser.

Comment: Worked :) write it as an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: Your PHP `header` is placed after HTML. So probably you will get error "Cannot send headers. Headers already started on..." (If your error reporting is set to ON). You must move your header to the top, that is before any HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect after 5 seconds, you can do something like this:

```
 <div>
    Please wait... Generating reports..
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function(){
      window.location.href = "result.php";
  },5000);
 </script>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=results.php" />
```

`content` is refresh time in seconds (in above example - 5 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Headers are already sent.
Try to use JavaScript, or set headers at the beginning of the script.

**JavaScript**
    window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

```
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Comment: As per the OP's logic you must enclose this inside `setTimeout()` for 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Place the `header` function before sending data to the browser.

```
<?php
header( "refresh:5; url=results.php" ); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
```

You don't need javascript here.